# Django TastyPie Resource Update Error

Tags: django, tastypie

I am updating a Django model using tastypie API from a mobile client using JQuery.
When I send the PUT request, I get the error that `Column 'created' cannot be null`.

The 'created' column is in my model to be updated which is of type

```
models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True).
```

When updating using tastypie API, the update causes this column to be set to `null` which throws an error.

The model can be successfully updated using django form directly. The error is caused only from the API update call. Not sure what could be the issue.

I tried changing the field to (`default=datetime.datetime.now, editable=False, blank=True`)
in place of `auto_now_add` but still it gave the same error. Let me know if anybody knows what the issue could be.

Here is part of the resource code:

```
class AbcResource(ModelResource):

    def obj_update(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        logger.debug("Update called")
        res = super(AbcResource, self).obj_update(bundle, request)
        signals.abc_updated.send( sender=request, abc=res.obj, user=request.user )
        return res
```

Here is part of the model:

```
class Abc( models.Model ):
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
```

There is no custom save method for the model.

Hers is the code to send the PUT request:

```
var url = root + "/api/v1/abc/" + selected_abc + "/" + "?user_key=" + user_guid + "&user_name=" + username + "&format=json";
var abc_data = xmlRequest(url, false);
abc_data["field"] = field_value;
var request = $.ajax({
                     url: url,
                     type: 'PUT',
                     contentType: 'application/json',
                     data: JSON.stringify(abc_data),
                     dataType: "application/json",
                     processData: false
                     })
request.done(function(msg) {
             console.log("Status update pass : " + msg);
             });

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
             console.log("Status update fail : " + jqXHR.responseText);
             console.log(jqXHR);
             });
```

Is more information required?

Comment: Could you post your Resource code and the model you are creating resource for.

Comment: Could you just post the exact the 'django form' code where the update works... I mean I'm interested whether you are calling the obj.save() or something else there, just to know what exactly is working to try and figure out the problem.

Comment: The update is not from the django form but from the javascript code that I have posted. Update from the form works fine. Also, I do not have any custom obj.save() method.

Comment: Would you just try for me the following:
In the obj_update method before calling the super(...).obj_update() try both of these versions:
1) bundle['created'] = datetime.datime.now() 2) bundle.created = datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: It still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Is there other fields than your DateTimeField in you model? using the PUT command will change completely your data, so you need a complete entry.
If you want to partially update a field try the PATCH command
http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#partially-updating-an-existing-resource-patch

Comment: I do send the complete data when trying to PUT. So, for editing a particular record, should I use PUT or PATCH?

Comment: I tried to use PATCH but received the same error when update was called.

Comment: Can you give us a complete example of your Model, ModelResource and data posted?